# Explain This Mount Option Please

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

On [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) it states to create the bind mount below in the fstab file so that we don't have to manually mount it on reboots. What I don't understand is the third option (none).

```
/home/users    /export/users   none    bind  0  0
```

According to the man page of fstab, it says the field options are like below, where the third field "describes the type of the filesystem". But in the NFS article it says to have "none" as the filesystem. How can you just not have a filesystem and then put files on it?

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One uses the "file system type" `none` for **bind** and **move mounts**.

That means, whenever we are not mounting a new file system but simply "move" or "copy" an already mounted file system mount point.

A bind mount just adds another location (mount point) through which we can access an already existing place from our file system. This can be an already mounted partition/device or any directory inside one. The move mount is similar but replaces one mount point with another instead of just adding a new one.

And as such "bind mounts" and "move mounts" do not need to take care of the underlying file systems because they are already mounted, we specify `none` as file system type in `/etc/fstab`.